# Is it possible to get Varnish to rebuild the whole site?

Tags: varnish

is it possible to set varnish to rebuild the whole site periodically? I have a play app behind  varnish. The app generated website numbers over 2,000 pages, most of which are product pages. Is it possible to set Varnish to start at the root of the site and follow every link/path to call the app to rebuild the site? And then schedule this for, say 2am?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, Varnish does not have a cache warming solution. If you want to rewarm your site you have to do it by some script or a wget with mirror option.

Varnish 4 will support background fetches. When a cache object is expired and the "first unlucky dude" hits that object, Varnish still serves the cached object while it fetches the new object at the background.

Comment: Please note that this 'unlucky dude' will only get a cached object if there's a grace period set, otherwise he'll get stuck till the page gets generated and served.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that Varnish does have the varnishreplay tool. You can set up a varnish log and use varnishreplay to parse the logs. This will rebuild the cache. Docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishreplay.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use wget to warm your cache:

```
wget -q http://www.domain.com/sitemap.xml -O - | egrep -o "http://www.domain\.com[^<]+" | wget --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0" -q -i - -O /dev/null
```

Using --header to simulate a Firefox browser.